# Have there ever been inter-faith debates between Jews and Zoroastrians?

Tags: history, gentiles, avodah-zarah

There are records of many inter-faith debates (disputations) between Jews and Christians even up to modern times. However I have never heard of similar such debates between Jews and Zoroastrians. Are there records of such debates ever having taken place? Are there transcripts?

---

<sup>Adapted from [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28414/2).</sup>

Comment: In Talmud and Medrash the 'debates' seem to be with Greeks and Romans. Some terms which might refer to the Zoroastrians are Chavar and Amgushi (Magi). Neither is used favorably. Offhand I don't remember any debates with them. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can weigh in. +1.

Comment: Seems like Jews; not Judaism.

Comment: @mevaqesh, imo it's safe to assume on this site, but it should be edited in explicitly, that the interfaith debate has Judaism on one side of it.

Comment: It sounds like a historical question of whether Jewish people did something; albeit something related to Judaism. I think this is the obvious intent of the question regardless of where it is asked. It seems more appropriate for the history stack exchange, IMO. @msh210

Comment: @mevaqesh re "It sounds like a historical question of whether Jewish people did something; albeit something related to Judaism": I agree completely. And that puts it squarely within this site's scope. It may possibly get better answers on [history.se], but it's the author's choice to ask it on any site where it falls in scope.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic since  such a debate could be completely about Zoroastrianism, this is not a question about Judaism itself, just as a Jewish publisher publishes mostly Jewish material, but a request for a list of all of their books which could include books not about Judaism, would be off-topic.